# Webpage Templates Golang

Tags: html, css, go

I am working on a website with golang as my back end.

I would like to load webpages with a particular background image inside of a div depending on the full URL. I have gotten HTML templates to work well and I am able to dynamically change text and a few other things based on this.

However in HTML5, as you cannot define the background image of a div in anything but CSS, I would like to know how I might have this image change dynamically as well. I do not know how to dynamically change CSS with go(using net/http and html/template), or even if this is possible. Thank you

Comment: Remember that `html/template` is simply a wrapper for `text/template` - which doesn't even remotely care if it is parsing CSS, HTML or your grandmothers shopping list.

Comment: Use what you already know to change dynamically change CSS, whether the CSS is specified in style attribute of the div or in a separate style element. Example: `<div style="background-image: {{.Image}}">`